# Split String with Python Regexp

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string like:

```
"|CLL23|STR. CALIFORNIA|CLL12|AV. PHILADELFIA 438|CLL10|AV. 234 DEPTO 34|"
```

I need to separate the string form next:

```
CLL23|STR.CALIFORNIA

CLL12|AV. TEXAS 345

CLL10|AV. 234 DEPTO 24
```

Try the following form:

```
r=re.compile('(?<=[|])([\w]+)')

v_sal=r.findall(v_campo)
print v_sal
```

Result:

```
['CLL23', 'CLL12', 'CLL10']
```

That way you could get the rest of the string in Python?

Comment: How is it that the sample output contains a line with `TEXAS` but no such line appears in the sample input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define your string:

```
>>> s = "|CLL23|STR. CALIFORNIA|CLL12|AV. PHILADELFIA 438|CLL10|AV. 234 DEPTO 34|"
```

Now, let's print the formatted form:

```
>>> print('\n'.join('CLL' + word.rstrip('|') for word in s.split('|CLL') if word))
CLL23|STR. CALIFORNIA
CLL12|AV. PHILADELFIA 438
CLL10|AV. 234 DEPTO 34
```

The above divides on `|CLL`.  This seems to work for your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution would be to [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string at every `'|'` and then print them in chunks:

```
s="|CLL23|STR. CALIFORNIA|CLL12|AV. PHILADELFIA 438|CLL10|AV. 234 DEPTO 34|"

s1=filter(None, s.split('|')) #split string and filter empty strings

for x,y in zip(s1[0::2], s1[1::2]):
    print x + '|' + y
```

**Output:**

```
>>> 
CLL23|STR. CALIFORNIA
CLL12|AV. PHILADELFIA 438
CLL10|AV. 234 DEPTO 34
```